# ngrx-data, getWithQuery() loaded$ observable doesn't emit boolean "true" even though data is loaded

Tags: angular, ngrx

I had a problem while implementing router-resolver via ngrx. I expect router to be resolved when the data is loaded to entityCache. The weird behaviour is I can clearly see data is loaded in entityCache via Chrome Devtools (Redux). Even though loading$ flag (observable) works correctly, loaded$ flag first emits ***false*** as expected, but doesn't emit ***true*** when the data is loaded to the store. There are workaround solutions, but I don't know if there is any built-in solution.

```
.
.
.
@Injectable()
export class BusDetailResolver implements Resolve<boolean>{
    
    constructor(
        ...,
        private busDetailEntityService:BusDetailEntityService,
    ){}

    private accessToken = '';
    ....



    resolve(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{

        return this.busDetailEntityService.loaded$
        .pipe(
            tap(x => console.log(x)),
            tap(loaded => {
                if(!loaded && this.accessToken != ''){
                    let queryParams:QueryParams = 
                    {   
                        routeCode: "exampleRCode",
                        direction: "exampleDirection"
                    };
                    
                    this.busDetailEntityService.getWithQuery(queryParams);
                }
            }),
            filter(loaded => !!loaded),
            first(),
        );

    }
}
```

when I subscribe in some component (without implementing router resolver), to the same service like this:

```
this.busDetailEntityService.getWithQuery(packet).subscribe(val => {
  console.log('data loaded:', val)
})
```

I can clearly see that data is loaded. In any case, loaded$ flag doesn't fire as true.

- Before Load

[image: Before Load State]

[image: Before Load Diff]

- After Load

[image: After Load State]

[image: After Load Diff]

**(as you can see loading$ works, loaded$ doesn't work)**

Comment: first() Maybe the issue?

Comment: @MikeOne I don't think so, the code doesn't even reach to the first(), can't pass the filter() because it doesn't emit true from loaded$.